# Kafka to google Pub/Sub using Sink Connector

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, google-cloud-pubsub

Sorry for the basic question.

Requirement:
Need to send json payload from spring boot application to google pub sub.

I have started implementing kafka producer and publishing message to topics and from there to kafka consumer is receiving the json.

Now i need to send the json payload from kafka consumer to google pub/sub.
Iam confused, should i need kafka consumer for this.. Or just from kafka producer to google pub sub i can send by using the kafka connector.jar and configuring in the topics in the properties.
Any help is much appreciated for this implementation

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pubsub/tree/master/kafka-connector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get messages from Kafka into Google Cloud Pub/Sub, you should not need to write your own consumer. You can create an instantiation of the [Google Cloud Pub/Sub Kafka connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pubsub/tree/master/kafka-connector). The [Kafka Connect](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect) service is usually part of the Kafka deployment itself, so you just need to start an instance of it configured to run the Cloud Pub/Sub sync connector. The README file for the connector details the steps that need to be taken, but to summarize:

1. Download the [latest release](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pubsub/releases/) and build it via the `mvn package` command.
2. Copy target/cps-kafka-connector.jar to a place in your Java path so it accessible when Kafka Connect runs.
3. Copy the [sink config](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pubsub/blob/2e0614e6d09d3e3ad9c1427fa6815f6d159d409e/kafka-connector/config/cps-sink-connector.properties) and change it to point to the appropriate Cloud Pub/Sub project and topic and the appropriate Kafka topics.
4. Make a copy of the config/connect-standalone.properties or config/connect-distributed.properties based on whether or not you want to have a single instance or multiple instances of the connector running.
5. Update the `key.converter` and `value.converter` properties to be `org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter`. This way, the connector will not try to interpret the data being passed but will instead just pass the JSON straight through to Cloud Pub/Sub.
6. Start up the connector with the appropriate command based on the standalone vs. distributed connector, e.g., `bin/connect-standalone.sh <standalone config file> <connector config file>`.

Messages should now be flowing from Kafka into Google Cloud Pub/Sub. If you are just using Kafka to go from Spring Boot to Cloud Pub/Sub, then you could avoid the Kafka step by setting up an [outbound channel adapter to send messages to Cloud Pub/Sub directly](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-gcp-pubsub/).

Comment: Thanks @Kamal Aboul-Hosn for the detailed explanation. Very much useful

Comment: Starting from [`v0.5 Alpha`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pubsub/releases/tag/v0.5-alpha) they are providing a [pre-built jar](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pubsub/releases/download/v0.5-alpha/pubsub-kafka-connector.jar) with the release. We can simply use that and avoid the step to build the package from source :)